# Thread logging data to text file - how to?

Tags: android, multithreading, logging, streamwriter

I tried to build a App that continuously write data in a text file.
I done this with a endless Thread (sleep-write data-sleep...).

Now I recognized, that the app is not continuously running in background - sometimes it does, sometimes not. Android paused the Thread? Why? If the App is in foreground, it run again.

I tried to put the thread in an service, but i dont get work the Permission issue.

How can I run a endless-repeating task in the background?

Comment: A service is your way to go. Could you provide your code? What do you mean with 'permission issue'? Which permission?

Comment: what is the android runtime version you're testing and your application target SDK? android restrains much of the background execution so you have to design carefully what you want to do in BG

Comment: I solve the permission problem (get the permission in "onCreate" actitity, not in the service class). It's working.

BUT Android is killing my service after 1-2 minutes idle time - so i have the same problem: the thread run not endless.

So I tried to create a foreground service, but the app is craching without error log.
https://www.dev2qa.com/android-foreground-service-example/
-> Not working